# SQL code - Using Case to classify customers - error 3625 but cannot find the error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying yo classify customers in three groups REMIC, REMIR and HC

Customers with number '682010','682020','683220' are HC --> else are REMIC or REMIR
REMIR = Has no Exposure at Default in Commercial Real Estate (04), but has exposure at default in residential (05)

I have created a case formula, however it keeps giving me the error 3625 - i know I should have counted right, so cannot see the error

```
select 

CU.CD03001 as "Local Customer ID",

case 
            when "Commercial Real Estate EAD" is null then 'O'
            else 'X'
end as "Commercial Status",

case 
            when "Residential Real Estate EAD" is null then 'O'
            else 'X'
end as "Residential Status",

case 
            when CU.CD03008='DK' 
                and CU.CD03025 not in ('682010','682020','683220')
                and "Commercial Status" = 'O'
                and "Residential Status" = 'X'
                then 'REMIR'

            when CU.CD03008='DK' 
                and CU.CD03025  in ('682010','682020','683220')
                then 'HC'
                else 'REMIC'

end as "Customer Group",

CU.CD03010 as Business_Partner_Name,
ORG1.CD01007_Cd as BA1,
ORG1.CD01008 as BA2,

BA2_NM.Acctng_unit_com_nm AS "Banking Unit",
    case ORG1.CD01008
        when '6002092' then ORG1.region_cd
        else ORG1.CD01009
        end as BA3,
BA3_NM.Acctng_unit_com_nm AS "Branch Region",

SD.Common_Cust_Seg_Lvl3_CD,
SD.Common_Cust_Seg_Lvl3_Desc,
CU.CD09075 as Rating,

COALESCE(sum(Case when CR.CD09076_Collateral_Category_Cd = '04' then CR.CD09014_Exposure_at_Default else 0 END),0)      as "Commercial Real Estate EAD",
COALESCE(sum(Case when CR.CD09076_Collateral_Category_Cd = '05' then CR.CD09014_Exposure_at_Default else 0 END),0)      as "Residential Real Estate EAD"

FROM PROD_INT_SL_DX_VIEWS.organization_dim                              ORG1

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 

                        Customer_Id,
                        CD03001,
                        CD03008,
                        CD03010,
                        CD03025,
                        CD03026,
                        CD03029,
                        CD09075

                        FROM PROD_INT_SL_DX_VIEWS.customer_dim

                        where   CD03025='L'
                            and     CD03008 = 'DK'
                        group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 )                                                  CU

    ON  ORG1.CD01001=CU.CD03026

 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CD01001, Acctng_unit_com_nm                           
                FROM   PROD_INT_SL_DX_VIEWS.ORGANIZATION_HIER) AS BA2_NM
    ON TRIM(ORG1.CD01008) = TRIM(BA2_NM.CD01001)

 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CD01001, Acctng_unit_com_nm                           
      FROM   PROD_INT_SL_DX_VIEWS.ORGANIZATION_HIER) AS BA3_NM
    ON TRIM(BA3) = TRIM(BA3_NM.CD01001)

LEFT JOIN PROD_INT_SL_DX_VIEWS.customer_segment_dim         SD
    ON  CU.CD03029=SD.CD03029

LEFT JOIN PROD_INT_SL_CPS_VIEWS.Financial_Fact                      FF
    on CU.Customer_Id=FF.Customer_Id

LEFT JOIN PROD_INT_SL_CPS_VIEWS.PRODUCT_DIM                     PD
   ON FF.Product_Party_Type_Id=PD.Product_Party_Type_Id

LEFT JOIN PROD_INT_SL_CPS_VIEWS.CREDIT_RISK_FACT                    CR
   ON FF.Agreement_Id=CR.Agreement_Id


where   BA1='6002000'
     and    BA2 in ('6002091')
     and    SD.Common_Cust_Seg_Lvl3_CD in ('C30100','C20100','C10100','RB_C50100','C60100')
     and    FF.Year_Month_Id in ('201409') and FF.period_type in ('AVGP','AVGY')
     and    FF.CD12001_Currency_Unit='EUR'
     and    PD.Language_Code='eng'

 group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
order by 1
```

Comment: what is `"Residential Real Estate EAD"` a column name?

Comment: Yes is is a column I created to sum up any Expsore at default (EAD) for Residential Real Estate, and did the same for Commercial.

Comment: what version of SQL server? have you tried replacing the quotes with square brackets? `[Residential Real Estate EAD]`

Comment: Yes, I have Teradata SQL assistant, I am sure that the problem lies in the three cases in the beginning, because if I take them out the query runs fine - but I need them to segment the customers.